# How to transform tabs and sub tabs into drop down items and sub items using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design

In HTML and CSS and RESPONSIVE web design how do I transform tabs into drop down items. I DON'T want to use any third party libraries like bootstrap. I pretty much did lot of angular work in the project. I don't want to use angular material either. I have this specific requirement in my project, I have html TABS and some of the tabs have SUB TABS in them. I want the tabs to be responsive. I want the tabs (TABS and SUB TABS) to become drop down menu when on mobile break point. I got the example in the below link, but it doesn't have sub tabs in it and obviously when it transforms to mobile view it can't show the sub items, which it doesn't has. I tried to modify the example by including the sub tabs but it didn't worked for me. Appreciate any ones help if they can modify the below example with sub tabs and on mobile view it transforms to drop down items and sub items. Here is the best link so far I found.

https://codepen.io/jpkempf/pen/Awxbo

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){

  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $('ul').toggleClass('expanded');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use bootstrap as frontend framework? Any reason for that? I'm just curious

Comment: I would love to, but client don't want to use it.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Normally bootstrap is ideal for this kind of task. Sadly I can't provide a non-bootstrap solution. Best of luck